# I am using a Batch File to search a list of functions for an exact match, wondering if its possible to do a keyword search instead

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, keyword

I am using a Batch File to search a list of functions for an exact match, wondering if its possible to do a key word search, so right now i have to type "open cmd" 
(variations on spacing and capital letters are accounted for) 
Id like to switch it over to a system that can look for "cmd" and perform the action so "hey, open cmd please" would yield the same result as the old system

Old system:

```
setlocal
:: /STARTUP
set speech=start scripts\nircmd.exe speak text
cls
:begin
set TALK=TypeSomething
SET /P TALK=
set TALK=%TALK:?=%
call :%TALK: =% 2>NUL
if %errorlevel% equ 0 goto begin
exit /B 0
:unknown
echo Old function no longer supported 
:opencmd
:BOSopencmd
:cmd
echo Command Prompt has now been opened in a new window, sir.
%speech% "Command Prompt has now been opened in a new window, sir."
start scripts\cmd.bat
exit /B 0
```

It is based of a chat bot i tried to make in middle school so the %speech% is not an important item, i can add that and the echo later. I just need a system that works like the old one if possible. The other i can have any number of functions with

```
:cmd
start cmd
Exit /B 0
```

or

```
:reddit
start http://www.reddit.com/
exit /B 0
```

at these need to be able to stack. I can transition to having scripts for each function in a separate batch files if needed. Ive tried trying findstr but it wasn't giving the desired results. Ive exhausted my knowledge on what i might be able to do but I've come up short lol, If you are having trouble understanding what i'm asking don't hesitate to let me know

I learn by taking things apart so partial code is appreciated but will not be much help until after I've figured out what does what .

Comment: Are you willing to use a tempfile as part of the process or do you wish to avoid file I/O?

Comment: I am open to just about anything if you are willing to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample of how you might approach it using `ECHO`, `FINDSTR`, and `CALL` (This is a modified example from the original per your request to be able to process multiple keywords):

```
@echo off
set TST_FNDFLG=FALSE
set TST_USRANS=
set /P TST_USRANS=Enter keywords: 
if "%TST_USRANS%" == "" goto ENDIT
echo %TST_USRANS% | findstr /i "CMD" >NUL 2>&1
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto TRYRED
call :DOCMD
:TRYRED
echo %TST_USRANS% | findstr /i "REDDIT" >NUL 2>&1
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto TRYGOO
call :DORED
:TRYGOO
echo %TST_USRANS% | findstr /i "GOOGLE" >NUL 2>&1
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto TRYEND
call :DOGOO
goto TRYEND
:DOCMD
if [%TST_FNDFLG%] == [FALSE] echo.
echo   CMD was found in "%TST_USRANS%"
set TST_FNDFLG=TRUE
goto :EOF
:DORED
if [%TST_FNDFLG%] == [FALSE] echo.
echo   REDDIT was found in "%TST_USRANS%"
set TST_FNDFLG=TRUE
goto :EOF
:DOGOO
if [%TST_FNDFLG%] == [FALSE] echo.
echo   GOOGLE was found in "%TST_USRANS%"
set TST_FNDFLG=TRUE
goto :EOF
:TRYEND
echo.
if [%TST_FNDFLG%] == [TRUE]  echo No more keywords found
if [%TST_FNDFLG%] == [FALSE] echo Did not find any known keywords
goto ENDIT
:ENDIT
echo.
set TST_USRANS=
set TST_FNDFLG=
```

Comment: I think i kinda get it so far but i need it to be able to work with more keywords

Comment: what i mean by more keywords is with the old way i was using i could stack                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
':cmd'
'start cmd'
'Exit /B 0'
on top of
':reddit'                                                                                                   
'start http://www.reddit.com/'
'exit /B 0'                                                                                                
with no spaces

Comment: Yes, this example merely shows how to search for keywords rather than matching entire strings.  You'd still need to adapt this for your use in the original script.

You could loop through the `ECHO` / `FINDSTR` loop and extract out the keywords you've already acted on.  I'd use the `CALL` command to have a subroutine designed to perform that removal.

Comment: I've modified it to process multiple keywords `CMD`, `REDDIT`, and `GOOGLE` (and this has never been case sensitive).